# Looking to generate a bar/pie chart based on data with java/jsp

Tags: java, jsp, graph, web

So in my database I store what browsers are used,and essentially what I would like to do is display the numbers using each browsers in a graph on my webpage. I can easily count the amount of each browser being used from my database.But I have no idea how I could use it to generate a bar chart and display it on my web page.Any ideas?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using a JavaScript library like highcharts and just get java to supply the data model via ajax call to servlet or embedded data inside jsp inside JavaScript tag and feed to library

http://www.highcharts.com